# Triggering connection pools with sqlalchemy in flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask + SQLAlchemy (DB is Postgres) for my server, and am wondering how connection pooling happens. I know that it is enabled by default with a pool size of 5, but I don't know if my code triggers it.

Assuming I use the default flask SQLalchemy bridge :

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And then use that object to place database calls like

```
db.session.query(......)
```

How does flask-sqlalchemy manage the connection pool behind the scene? Does it grab a new session every time I access db.session? When is this object returned to the pool (assuming I don't store it in a local variable)?

What is the correct pattern to write code to maximize concurrency + performance? If I access the DB multiple times in one serial method, is it a good idea to use db.session every time?

I was unable to find documentation on this manner, so I don't know what is happening behind the scene (the code works, but will it scale?)

Thanks!

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: I don't know how my server will respond under heavy load - will multiple concurrent requests coming in at the same time block? Will they be treated correctly? Will I be taking/returning objects to the pool more than I have to? Will the pool expand more than it has to?

Comment: I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy and get 70+ concurrent connection and it works just fine.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily answer how it works. I know that it does infact work. I believe ( could be mistaken ) that reddit use SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I think it uses SQLAlchemy's [scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session), if you're referring on how SQLAlchemy handles sessions.

Comment: There are many ways to use SQLAlchemy's API, and that (API misuse) is what I'm afraid of, which is why i'm looking for clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event registration - http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html#event-registration
There are many different event types that can be monitored, `checkout`, `checkin`, `connect` etc... - http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html

Here is a basic example from the docs on printing a when a new connection is established.

```
from sqlalchemy.event import listen
from sqlalchemy.pool import Pool

def my_on_connect(dbapi_con, connection_record):
    print "New DBAPI connection:", dbapi_con

listen(Pool, 'connect', my_on_connect)
```